# Strange recent search terms

Tags: search

I've noticed on the backend under recent and top search terms several strange searches.

'EKGQ') AND 4671=CAST((CHR(113)||CHR(116)||CHR(117)||CHR(97)||CHR(113))||(SELECT (CASE WHEN (4671=4671) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))::tex

EKGQ%' AND (SELECT 4655 FROM(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x7174756171,(SELECT (CASE WHEN (4655=4655) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),0x7169756471

EKGQ%' AND 4671=CAST((CHR(113)||CHR(116)||CHR(117)||CHR(97)||CHR(113))||(SELECT (CASE WHEN (4671=4671) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))::text

EKGQ%' AND 6277=CONVERT(INT,(SELECT CHAR(113)+CHAR(116)+CHAR(117)+CHAR(97)+CHAR(113)+(SELECT (CASE WHEN (6277=6277) THEN CHAR(49

There are about 20 of those in different variations over the past few weeks, any ideas as to what they are/where they are coming from? They seem to return all products in my store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are tries to [SQL-Inject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) your installation. I don't know whether there was a securite issue in the past, afaik there is no, so no need to worry about.